# Get column name of property mapped with Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

How can I access the Hibernate mapping of my model to find out the column name of a property?

The column name is not specified in the mapping so Hibernate generates it automatically - I would like to create a native SQL statement including this column name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Thanks to Jherico I found out how to do that:

```
((Column) sessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration().getClassMapping(Person.class.getName())
        .getProperty("myProperty").getColumnIterator().next()).getName();
```

Comment: What is "sessionFactoryBean" here? I am sure it is not sessionFactory.

Comment: it can be either sessionFactory or SessionFactoryBean, it depends on the version

Answer (score 3):

```
((AbstractEntityPersister) sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(o.getClass()))
    .getPropertyColumnNames(property)[0];
```

Comment: You should use `Hibernate.getClass(o)` rather than `o.getClass()` in case `o` is a proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have access to the Hibernate Configuration object.

Answer (score 1):

This will retrieve one-level composites and normal property mappings:

```
String columnName(String name) {
    PersistentClass mapping = configuration.getClassMapping(ExtendedPerson.class.getName());
    Property property = mapping.getProperty(name);
    if(property.isComposite()){
        Component comp = (Component) property.getValue();
        property = comp.getProperty(StringHelper.unroot(name));
        assert ! property.isComposite(); //go only one level down 
    }
    Iterator<?> columnIterator = property.getColumnIterator();
    Column col = (Column) columnIterator.next();
    assert ! columnIterator.hasNext();
    return col.getName();
}
```