# How To retrieve Column name in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I want to retrieve Column name and table name of Entities in JPA
I know if i have Annotation I can retrieve Column name by getting Annotation.
but my classes hasn't Annotation, they have mapped by hbm files
So, How can I retrieve column names?

Comment: Some code which you tried

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2023894/655756