# Get table column names in Hibernate

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I am using hibernate `Criteria` class to get all records of table :

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(AppTaskConfig.class)
```

I would like to get column names also as I need to convert result set into JSON format.

Comment: Can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2023700/366964 might help.

Answer (score 16):

To get the `column names`, first you need to find the `properties` of the entity using `org.hibernate.metadata.ClassMetadata`:

```
ClassMetadata classMetadata = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(AppTaskConfig.class);
String[] propertyNames = classMetadata.getPropertyNames();
```

where `propertyNames` is an array of Strings representing the property names of `AppTaskConfig`.

Now using Hibernate `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration` object you can find the column names of the `properties`:

```
for (String property : propertyNames) {
    Configuration configuration = sessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration();
    PersistentClass persistentClass = configuration
                    .getClassMapping(Details.class.getName());
    String columnName = ((Column) persistentClass.getProperty(property)
                    .getColumnIterator().next()).getName();
}
```

Comment: What is sessionFactoryBean here? I don't think it is sessionFactory.

Comment: @instanceOfObject , Please check the link https://developer.jboss.org/thread/189593?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: @ Saikai while follow this approach  we are not getting the primary key details . Please provide one more solution.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to get column name with hibernate 5

```
final AbstractEntityPersister classMetadata = (AbstractEntityPersister) sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(clazz)
final String[] names = classMetadata.getPropertyColumnNames(property)
```

With hibernate 4, I do just like @Debojit Saikia

Comment: `getClassMetadata()` is now deprecated.  [Here is a link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43799491/2031150) to a SO answer which suggests a Hibernate 5 alternative.

Answer (score 0):

What are column names of entity? Entity could use some of the table's columns and don't have fields for other.

Entity could extend another Entity class so fields of the Entity class are represented by columns from different tables.

You can run native SQl query and see table columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] columnNames = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Employee.class).getPropertyNames();

  org.hibernate.type.Type[] columnTypes = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Employee.class).getPropertyTypes();
```

try this this is work properly...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reflection API to access to declared JPA annotations of a field/getter like Column o JoinColumn.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;

// get declared field
Field field = persistentClass.getDeclaredField("property");

// get declared method
Method method = persistentClass.getMethod("get"+property.substring(0,1).toUpper()+property.substring(1)));

// access to declared annotations or field or method to find Column or JoinColumn
```