# Get physical column value with entity property value using hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a table T with columns defined as usual.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T")
public class T {
@Column(name="test_id")
private Long testId;

}
```

Given entity property "testId", I want to get corresponding DB column name (i.e. "test_id"). How could it be achieved?

**Edit 1:**
I want to keep this column at separate location with actual DB column name (test_id) than testId. I fetched these values from DB using HQL which have key as entity name (i.e. testId) and I want actual column name in DB.

Comment: could you please clarify your requirements? Do you want to rename the field in your code?

Comment: No, I don't want to rename. I just want to fetch db column_name corresponding to entity columnName.

Comment: Just curious: why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have got these logical values from HQL and want to store physical column name in the audit to keep track of the changes made on that column.

Comment: It seems meaningless. Because you still have to provide a string which is the name of your field instead string of column name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your requirement correctly, you want to use HQL while having a consistent name for both DB column and the entity field, like this:

```
SELECT t.test_id FROM Test t
```

instead of

```
SELECT t.testId FROM Test t
```

There is only one way to do that - renaming the field to `test_id`. HQL works on entities, not on DB tables, so you must use proper field names in the query.

Since `test_id` contradicts the usual Java coding conventions, I would advise against it.

EDIT: Getting the annotation attribute value with reflection would work along this outline:

```
Field field = MyEntity.class.getDeclaredField("testId");
Column a = field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
String columnName = a.name();
```

Comment: I understand that HQL works on entities. What I want is to get DB column name from entity property (get test_id from testId). 
I have read that Hibernate Configurations could be used for this but not quite sure of the way.

Comment: So you want to extract the `name` attribute of the Column annotation, you could use reflection for that. Or am I misunderstanding you again?

Comment: Correct! Reflection is one way to do this :)

Answer (score 3):

I would try to avoid this by any means, but if you're really sure you'll need it, use:

```
Configuration configuration = sessionFactory.getConfiguration();
PersistentClass persistentClass = configuration
                .getClassMapping(T.class.getName());
String columnName = ((Column) persistentClass.getProperty("testId")
                .getColumnIterator().next()).getName();
```

See also [Get table column names in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418500/get-table-column-names-in-hibernate)