# Hibernate output name of columns

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest

i am want output name of columns from table of my database on MySql. I am use Rest on Java, maven, tomcat, hibernate.

this code not work:

personDao.java:

```
public List<Person> getHeaders() {
    List<Person> persons = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        persons = session.createQuery("SHOW FIELDS FROM person").list();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (session != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            session.close();
        }
    }
    return persons;
}
```

service.java:

```
 @GET
@Path("/getHeaders")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<Person> getHeaders() {
    return personDao.getHeaders();
}
```

Please help me, how output name of columns ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the information_schema database and then use a standard hibernate query definition. In the information schema you can use a query as:

```
select * from COLUMNS WHERE table_name='person';
```

Comment: thank you, please explain more. What information and where I should put

Answer (score 0):

You can see this post: [Get column name of property mapped with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023700/get-column-name-of-property-mapped-with-hibernate)

> ```
> ((Column) sessionFactoryBean.getConfiguration().getClassMapping(Person.class.getName())
>      .getProperty("myProperty").getColumnIterator().next()).getName();
> ```

and [Get table column names in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418500/get-table-column-names-in-hibernate)