# Get original column mapping name from Jaxb object

Tags: java, jaxb

If there is a jaxb object with the following:

```
@Persist
@ColumnMapping(columnName = "foo_bar")
protected String fooBar;
```

Is there a way to retrieve the column name 'foo_bar' in my Java code somehow using 'fooBar' **without changing the jaxb object**?

Comment: I guess it would be something in this direction -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192552/get-value-of-a-parameter-of-an-annotation-in-java :/ Couldn't find anything relative to your question in JaxB docs.

Comment: Now I see that the annotations that you use aren't part of JaxB. Is that your data model? Check this tread maybe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023700/get-column-name-of-property-mapped-with-hibernate

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work with entity.getClass().getDeclaredField("fooBar").getAnnotation(some.path.annotations.ColumnMapping.class).columnName(); (it can be cleaned up obviously, but the basic idea works)

Comment: Really dislike this approach but you can't do much more since you have no control on the domain models.